# How to receive property change events in an AbstractInformationControl

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am working on an editor plugin and now implementing support for code hovers.

I have extended **AbstractInformationControl** (and implemented **IInformationControlExtension2**) to create a new control for showing the hover info.

It works almost fine, but I am unable to receive property change events in my information control. What I try is like this, but the event handler does not fire:

```java
public class MyHoverInfoControl extends AbstractInformationControl implements IInformationControlExtension2 {
    public MyHoverInfoControl(Shell parentShell, String string) {
    super(parentShell, string);
    create();
    Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

The control itself contains a **StyledText**. I have also tried to add a KeyListener to this **StyledText** to see if key events are received, and it only seemed to work if I click into the control (it is not enough to hover over a text to show the control). But property change event does not seem to be received even after the click.

Is it possible to receive property change events for an **AbstractInformationControl** subclass?

Comment: Changes to what properties? That listener is only listening for changes in the preferences for your plug-in.

Comment: We are expecting notification about changes to a property defined by our own plugin. (The value of the property can be correctly queried inside the control).